# Binding Run inside Textblock results in exception in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I'm trying to bind two `<Run>`s inside a `TextBlock` as shown in the snippet below. But I'm getting an `XamlParseException`.

Basically I'm trying to achieve this format:

**CodeNum:** LongDescription

If the below code is doomed to fail what other alternatives do I have?

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding CodeNum}"/>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text=": "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding LongDescription}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm guessing that either `LongDescription` or `CodeNumis` is a read-only property (doesn't have public setter). You need to change binding to be one way for all read-only properties that you use in `Run`

```
<Run Text="{Binding LongDescription, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: I believe, by default, binding mode of `Run` element is one way only. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks dkozl, actually changing the mode to `OneWay` solved the problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no `Run` by default binds `Text` both ways and it will cause exception if property doesn't have public setter.

Comment: But I'm surprised by `XamlParseException`. Such a misleading exception isn't it? It suggests that xaml is wrong. I have no Ide to check this at the moment.

Comment: There is a inner exception that explains the problem

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Lucky you, my application just went into break mode without telling me ANYthing about the source of the exception. I'm just glad it was the only thing I recently changed so I knew binding my run to an expression-bodied property was at fault. Searching for the reason why was painful enough. I just wonder now, why is it like that? I can bind to the Text property of the TextBlock just fine without a setter, why does Run behave different?

Comment: Can anyone explain (or point to the relevant docs for) the reasoning why `Run` has a default `Mode=TwoWay`? I mean, is the user able to change the text I bind to a `Run` in any way? The way I see it, `Run` is just a way to bind different snippets of read-only text within a single `TextBlock`. Am I wrong?