# Styling text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is this possible to stylize text in Label/Button/TextBlock in WPF? I mean something like making one word **Bold** and another *Italic*? In android it looks like this https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/styling-internationalized-text-in-android-f99759fb7b8f but I can't find any equivalent in WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

```
  <TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Text="I am bold" />
    <Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="I am italic" />
    <Run TextDecoration="Underline" Text="I am underlined" />
    <Run ForeGround="Yellow" Text="I am yellow" />
  </TextBlock.Inlines>
```

Comment: Okay, so another question. Is it possible to write text in resx file which ll behave like Your text? Eg. "<b> I am bold </b>  <i> I am italic <\i>"

Comment: Yes, you can do this via binding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551372/binding-run-inside-textblock-results-in-exception-in-wpf